# Add php if else to html code

Tags: php, html, sql, if-statement

I need help with how to add an "if else" statement to my php script, I need the `new_license_issued_date` field to be null if null and not `01/01/1970` like it's currently pulling through.... please help! thanks

```
 <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='display' id='table' width='100%'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Emp Code</th>   
        <th width='130'>Emp Name</th>
        <th width=100>Manager</th>
        <th width=150>Business Unit</th>
        <th width=240>Training Course Name</th>     
        <th width=65>Issued Date</th>
        <th width=65>Expiry Date</th>
        <th width=100>Cert Number</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    //display the results 
    while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>
        <td width=40>" . $row['Emp Code'] . "</td>
        <td>". $row['new_EmployeeName']  . "</td>
        <td>". $row['Manager'] . "</td>     
        <td>". $row['BusinessUnit'] . "</td>
        <td>". $row['new_TrainingCourseLookName'] . "</td>
        <td>". date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['new_license_issued_date'])) . "</td>
        <td>". date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['new_license_expiry_date'])) . "</td>
        <td>". $row['new_license_no'] . "</td>
    </tr>";
    }

    echo "</tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
        <p><a href='index.php'><< Back to Portal</p>
    </div>";
    //close the connection
    mssql_close();
    ?>  
    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.js">                        </script>

    <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('table').dataTable();
            } );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ternary operator.

```
<td>". (is_null($row['new_license_issued_date']) 
               ? "NULL" 
               : date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['new_license_issued_date']))) ."</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
($row['new_license_issue_date'] ? date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['new_license_issue_date'])) : '&nbsp');
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Or if it's more easy for you use this:

```
echo "<td>";

   if($row['new_license_issued_date'] !== NULL){
      echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['new_license_issued_date']));
   } else {
      echo "&nbsp;";
   }

echo "</td>";
```

Comment: use `!==` instead of `!=`

Comment: You're right ... I have not seen ... thanks for the correction!